# How to find if a given number is a composite number

Tags: java, math

How to identify if a given number is a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) number or not?

Comment: Does this mean your homework is to write a program to find the factors of a number?  And you're confused on how to count the number of factors?  If so, please mark the question with the [Homework] tag, and provide the complete problem exactly as it appears on your homework.  It's funnier when people copy and paste the entire assignment.

Comment: The page you linked to has one algorithm for this on it: [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). There's also a link on the bottom of that page which takes you to a [Java applet](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) (with source) which does this. Is there some particular problem you're having? Do those solutions not work for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if it's divisible by any number between 2 and the square root of the number, inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Ignacio's solution but if you wanted to make it more efficient (with respect to time, at the cost of a little space), you can just divide by all the *primes* between 2 and the square root of `n`.

That's because, if a number is not divisible by 2, there's no point checking if it's divisible by 4 or 6 or 8 (and so on).

For a 32-bit signed number, the square root of the highest (2147483647) is 46341 (rounded up).

46341<sup>2</sup> is 2147488281.

Since there are only about 4800 primes less than or equal to 46341, it's a simple matter to pre-generate them with a sieve and use those pre-generated values. The complete program that follows contains a function which returns the first prime factor for a composite or -1 for a prime. The program itself lists all the 32-bit numbers greater than 1 along with their prime/composite status and factors:

```
public class testprog {
    private static int[] primes = new int[] {
           2,    3,    5,    7,   11,   13,   17,   19,   23,   29,
          31,   37,   41,   43,   47,   53,   59,   61,   67,   71,
          73,   79,   83,   89,   97,  101,  103,  107,  109,  113,
         127,  131,  137,  139,  149,  151,  157,  163,  167,  173,
         179,  181,  191,  193,  197,  199,  211,  223,  227,  229,

       // : : : : :
       // Full list removed due to SO size limits.
       // You can get a full list from a sieve or off the net.
       // : : : : :

       45863,45869,45887,45893,45943,45949,45953,45959,45971,45979,
       45989,46021,46027,46049,46051,46061,46073,46091,46093,46099,
       46103,46133,46141,46147,46153,46171,46181,46183,46187,46199,
       46219,46229,46237,46261,46271,46273,46279,46301,46307,46309,
       46327,46337
    };
```

```
    private static int getFactor (int val) {
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
            if (primes[i] * primes[i] > val) {
                return -1;
            }
            if ((val / primes[i]) * primes[i] == val) {
                return primes[i];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 2; i < 2147483647; i++) {
            int val = i;
            int factor = getFactor (val);
            System.out.print ("Factors of " + val + " are:");
            while (factor != -1) {
                System .out.print (" " + factor);
                val = val / factor;
                factor = getFactor (val);
            }
            if (val == i)
                System .out.println (" " + val + " (prime)");
            else
                System .out.println (" " + val + " (composite)");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Java, the simplest option is to just call `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`, e.g. `BigInteger.valueOf(2147488279L).isProbablePrime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Composite means that the number is not a prime number.
Primes are difficult to find after a while, but anything that is a multiple of $2 ... sqrt(n)$ can be a factor of a composite number.  The range greater than this is not possible as the highest factor is $sqrt(n)$.

It sounds like you just didn't understand what composite meant?

If you don't know much programming (since it's unclear from your question) you can use a loop:

```
1 public class CompositeCheck {
2 
3   public static void main (String args[]) {
4       int number = 561;
5       System.out.print(isComposite(number));
6   }
7   
8   public static boolean isComposite(int number) {
9       int i;
10      for (i = 2; i< Math.sqrt(number); ++i){
11          if (number/i == Math.floor(number/i)) {
12              return true;
13          }
14      }
15  return false;
16  }
```

The "trick" is by division and comparing that to a rounded down version (line 11)

And if this is homework you should really tag it "homework" too and ask for help in the proper way.

Comment: what if its not a homework, I don't understand why people get annoyed (I do agree that it might look silly). But I would expect them to stay from answering if "they" feel its silly. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: "Composite means that the number is not a prime number" - Not necessarily. 0 and 1 are not prime, but nor are they composite.